# Interesting topologies or "metrics" on sets of logical sentences.

Tags: general-topology, logic, metric-spaces

I was wondering whether there are some known topologies on collection of logical sentences. I have thus far encountered the product topology on discrete atomic sentences, which I think is used to prove the completeness theorem.

My question is whether there are some other note-worthy topologies for predicate logic. I was hoping for some generalized pseudo-metric that takes into account provabilty.

I had in mind the notion of an abstract simplicial complex, where cells are logically consistent sentences, but was wondering whether there is already material on the subject which I can read on.

I would appreciate any remarks and references that would expand my knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

intuitionistic logic has a topological semantics, in which you interpret propositions as open sets, and classical logic results to be complete on the one point space. You can find about that in the chapter "intuitionistic logic" in the 3rd volume of the handbook of philosophical logic. Also, you should check about the relationship between topology and computability, which has beautiful results such as continuous = computable

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The first part of your seems unclear to me. What do you mean by propositions are open sets? You mean corresponding singletons are open sets? Also can you reference a source regarding the relation between continuity and computability?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur for the first part, you can _interpret_ proposition as open sets in a topological space $X$ and logical connectives as operations on open set, eg if $\phi \mapsto A$ and $\psi\mapsto B$, then $(\phi \to \psi) $ is Int($A^c \cup B$). If you do so, you can define "$\phi$ is true" as cl$(A)=X$, for every open set $A$ such that you can set $\phi\mapsto A$. A proposition is true under this definition in all topological spaces iff it is a theorem of intuitionistic logic.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur for the second part, i'm sorry, i'm also searchin some texts about this, but for the moment i only have a pdf in italian written by my logic professor